# Javascript Replace with Global not working on Caret Symbol

Tags: javascript

i have following code for replacing

```
 var temp =  "^hall^,^restaurant^";
 temp.replace(/^/g, '');
 console.log(temp);
```

This does not Replace the ^ symbol from string. How can this not work?

Comment: Try to escape it `\^`

Comment: Use escape `/\^/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 temp = temp.replace(/\^/g, '');
```

It is replacing once you escape the caret.

https://jsfiddle.net/ym7tt1L8/

And note that just writing `temp.replace(/\^/g, '');` doesn't update your actual string. That is the reason you have to write

```
 temp = temp.replace(/\^/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

In RegEx, the caret symbol is a recognized as a special character. It means the beginning of a string.

Additionally, replace **returns** the new value, it does not perform the operation in place, youneed to create a new variable.

For your case, you have to do one of the following:

```
var temp =  "^hall^,^restaurant^";
var newString = temp.replace(/\^/g, ''); // Escape the caret
```

Or simply replace the character without using RegEx at all:

```
var temp =  "^hall^,^restaurant^";
while (temp.indexOf('^') >= 0) {
    temp = temp.replace('^', '');
}
```

Alternative version:

```
var temp =  "^hall^,^restaurant^";
var newString = temp.split('^').join('');
```

Comment: The second code for replace will only replace a single ^. Not all the symbols so that is why Regex is needed.

Comment: I changed the non-regex version to output the same result. Might be pointless, but it illustrates an alternative way of doing it without RegEx.